# birrational morphisms caracterization

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Tomorrow I have to solve this:

> Let φ : X → Y be a morphism defined between affine entire algebraic varieties then prove:
>
> φ is birrational if and only if I can find two basic open subsets $U_a \subset X \:$ and $ \ U_b \subset Y \:$ where φ : $U_a$ → $U_b \:$ is an isomorphism

The definition of birratonal that Im using says that a morphism defined between affine entire algebraic varieties is a birratinal if and only if φ($0_X$)=$0_Y\: $ and the function field morphism defined by φ is an isomophism.

My Attemp:

$\Rightarrow$
I want to find those open subsets, as the k-algebras induced by X and Y are finite generated I can  express the generators of $A_x$ (the k-algebra induced by Y) as polinomyals of $B_y$ after that I dont know what to do, im trying to find some subsets to localizate

Comment: What are $0_X$ and $0_Y$?